# CodeMirror 5.62.3: Issues with the scrollbar, size of the editor, and line wrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar, codemirror

While I was writing HTML/CSS/JS, I really needed CodeMirror for the code editor part (I chose C# as the language mode for the editor; you can ignore the code in the editor). The issue I'm facing with CodeMirror version 5.62.3 is, I want the scrollbar to appear. However, the size of the editor is a little fishy, as I wanted its height to be 100% (so that the same size as the HTML document) and it doesn't look like 100% at all, and the scrollbar does show up, but it is completely static. So when I try to scroll, it's never scrolling.

Maybe it's an unstable release of CodeMirror, or maybe my browser malfunctioning, I have no idea. That's because not only there are issues with the size and the scrollbar being static, but also it never scrolls even when I scroll with my mouse, and also line wrapping does no effect. The only way to scroll is by scrolling the entire HTML document, which is not what I want.

I am sorry if there's a very obvious way to solve this issue. Even though I've read some of the documentations, but I don't really understand the full functionality of CodeMirror. And I couldn't find any relevant information, so keep in mind with that.

I'll paste the full HTML page. That's because it contains everything we need to debug the issue and view the code and no other unwanted code that's not relevant to the issue. Keep in mind I had to rename the name of the project to "something".

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.62.3/codemirror.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.62.3/codemirror.min.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.62.3/mode/clike/clike.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.62.3/theme/monokai.min.css">
        <title>something</title>
        <style>
            .CodeMirror {
                line-height: 28px;
                font-family: Lucida Console;
                overflow: auto;
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="editor"></div>
        <script>
            var editor = CodeMirror(document.getElementById("editor"), {
      mode: "text/x-csharp",
      lineNumbers: true,
      indentUnit: 4,
      tabSize: 4,
      theme: "monokai",
      lineWrapping: true,
      value: `// Welcome to something!\n// something allows you to test out C# and MSIL online.\n\n// x is supported!\n// You can run x and x for fully free.\n\// You can do so by going into the gear icon on the right.\n\n// something is still in beta!\n// So expect some classes, methods, or properties not yet to be implemented.
      \n// Note: something is not any associated with Microsoft.\n\n// Happy coding! :)\n\nusing System;\n\nnamespace Solution1\n{\n    internal sealed class Program\n    {\n        internal static void Main(string[] args)\n        {\n            Console.WriteLine("Demo test app!");\n            Environment.Exit(0);\n        }\n    }\n}`
    });
    editor.setSize("50%", "100%");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Try scrolling and using the scrollbar in the editor. That will not work.

I'm using the latest version of Google Chrome - chrome 116.

I appreciate any help or suggestions.

Also, it's important to mention that **I'm not using Node.js**. For example, I load all JavaScript libraries via a CDN.

Best regards,
-winscripter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of debugging, I found the issue.

This:
`editor.setSize("50%", "100%");`

is not correct. I thought "100%" means the size of the HTML document, but that's not correct. To yield the same effect, we need to use `100vh` instead:

`editor.setSize("50%", "100vh");`

And remove `overflow: auto` in CSS.